# Battery state of charge

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design

I am working with a 12 volt car battery.  I want to design a circuit to measure its state of charge.

Is there any specific IC to do that?

This battery will be used in an automobile robot, which will be driven by an STM32 controller.  There will also be a display screen, one of its functions is to display the battery state of charge. The battery supposed to work for 5 hours.

Comment: I am sure you think this is a straightforward question. But state of charge of lead acid batteries is kind of a can of worms. Are you sure you really need/want to measure the state of charge? Can you tell us more about the system? How long will the battery last? 1 hour? 1 day? Several days? Don't answer here. Edit the original question.

Comment: What do you have access to or already have? An MCU?

Comment: Have you looked on here for similar questions?

Comment: there exist specialised sensors because this is a hard problem.

Comment: What you can do is identify when to stop charging, and when to stop discharging. Estimating SOC and how long it's going to run is not possible, with anything that pretends to any useful accuracy.

Comment: @mkeith is it clear now?

Comment: @winny I am going to use STM32 MCU

Comment: @SolarMike yeah but couldn't find anything usefull

Comment: Would it be acceptable to just have 3 or 4 levels? If so you may be able to use a very simple model that uses voltage and discharge current to calculate SOC.

Comment: @Jasen could you tell me what is it?

Comment: So asking for products makes this a shopping question...

Comment: @mkeith yes it will be acceptable with 4 levels because I want to know when will I need to charge the battery.

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/331078/152903 but many others to look at.

Comment: @SolarMike I am asking for electrical solution to implement on my board

Comment: So what you are asking for is for one of us to design and then send you the solution?

Comment: @SolarMike of course not, I thought there will be some kind of circuit or ICs that will do the job, if not so case closed

Comment: That will greatly simplify things. I'm sure you can find example code. Worst case scenario, a linear SOC curve with a long enough low pass filter to remove any second order effects will probably get you close enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lead-acids are impressively complex in regard to state of charge modelling (Li-ion are way better).

You can be more or less confident about where 100% and 0% are. In the intermediate states, it is a matter of 1V change for a 12V battery and you are pretty much able to change the open circuit voltage of a flooded lead-acid battery by 0.2-0.3V just by shaking it (i.e. mixing charged and discharged electrolyte). It also has recovery times after removing the load in order of magnitude of hours or tens of minutes (electrolyte diffusion).

If you need to be exact, a culometric approach is your only option. Shunt + sampling the load current + integration.

For a predictable load, one can make a calibration curve of a particular battery (voltage under load vs time). But, don't expect wonder.